# Access to the furthest parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wondering how can I `addClass` to the furthest parent from `li`, I tried this and it working fine but I'm feel it's a bad logic, isn't it?

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass('myClass');
  });
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> <!-- I want to add class to this parent -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Click</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to something like `closest()` that work for `children`, is there a way to access grand `parent`? in this example I forced to write `parent()` six times!

Comment: `.closest()`, try this.

Comment: How are you identifying the "furthest" parent? The one just below `body`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I put comment for it in `html`

Comment: I saw the comment; it wasn't clear. Yes, it's just under `body` **in the example**, but that doesn't mean that's your real use case.

Comment: `.parents(":not(body)").last()`, see the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, in my project it's not under `body`, I think I found the solution with that topic @maiorano84

Comment: Normally you mark the parent with say another class, or some sort of attribute you can find on, and then just use closest on this.

Comment: @tourtravel: Well, which is it? It's either the one just under body (the question you answered "yes" to) or not (your most recent comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `$(this).parents([optional]).eq(n)`

**Update :**

Here are some properties if we `console.log($(this).parents())` and `console.log($(this).parents('div'))`, the flexibility of `.eq(n)` is maybe  not every time we want the outermost one:

$(this).parents()

```
{
  "0": <ul>…</ul>,
  "1": <div>…</div>,
  "2": <div>…</div>,
  "3": <div>…</div>,
  "4": <div>…</div>,
  "5": <div class="myClass">…</div>,
  "6": <body>…</body>,
  "7": <html>…</html>,
  "length": 8,
  ...
```

$(this).parents('div')

```
{
  "0": <div>…</div>,
  "1": <div>…</div>,
  "2": <div>…</div>,
  "3": <div>…</div>,
  "4": <div class="myClass">…</div>,
  "length": 5,
 ...
```

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
     $(this).parents().eq(5).addClass('myClass');
     // Or 
     // $(this).parents('div').eq(4).addClass('myClass');
     console.log($(this).parents('div'));
  });
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> <!-- I want to add class to this parent -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Click</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the `.last()` among all of the `.parents()` of the element.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div').last().addClass('myClass');
  });
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> <!-- I want to add class to this parent -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Click</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```